# If DirectoryInfo contain a Directory

Tags: c#, contains, directoryinfo

I'm tring the test to see if a `DirectoryInfo[]` contains a directory
my code is below

```
DirectoryInfo[] test = dir.GetDirectories();
if(test.Contains(new DirectoryInfo(dir.FullName +"\\"+ "Test_Folder")))
{
    ContainsTestFolder = true;
}
```

To me this should work but it does not seem to return true when it should. Any ideas to what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Maybe you can check like `test.Any(d => d.FullName == dir.FullName +"\\"+ "Test_Folder")`

Comment: It's worth noting that you shouldn't use `dir.FullName + "\\" + "Test_Folder"` when you could easily do `Path.Combine(dir.FullName, "Test_Folder")` as that is the more appropriate way to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Enumerable.Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697.aspx)

```
DirectoryInfo[] test = dir.GetDirectories();
if (test.Any(r => r.FullName.Equals(Path.Combine(dir.FullName,"Test_Folder"))))
{
   ContainsTestFolder = true;
}
```

The reason you are not getting the desired result is, Contains compare object reference, not its values. Also consider using [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx) instead of concatenating paths.

Answer (score 3):

You tried to compare two complex objects where all properties are not equals, prefer just comparing their `FullName` properties.

Prefer using predicate use `FirstOrDefault` and compare Directories' FullName

`FirstOrDefault` returns an object if found and `null` if not found

```
DirectoryInfo[] test = dir.GetDirectories();
if (test.FirstOrDefault(x => x.FullName.Equals(Path.Combine(dir.FullName,"Test_Folder"))) != null)
{
   ContainsTestFolder = true;
}
```

You can use also `Any` predicate which return a `bool`.

```
DirectoryInfo[] test = dir.GetDirectories();
if (test.Any(x => x.FullName.Equals(Path.Combine(dir.FullName,"Test_Folder"))))
{
    ContainsTestFolder = true;
}
```

Comment: This anwser was a very close second if I could I would have gived 2 upvotes for also answering why my code did not work. But Habib was the first person to use `.Any` that I seen and I was looking to return a bool

Comment: No need to get that test folder ?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot test it this way because you're checking 2 different objects which have one property the same for equality.

Try

```
DirectoryInfo[] test = dir.GetDirectories();
if (test.Any(x => x.FullName.Equals(dir.FullName +"\\"+ "Test_Folder")))
{
   ContainsTestFolder = true;
}
```

Comment: I can't find `Exists` function any idea ?

Comment: Got me there. I wasn't paying enough attention. Exists is defined upon List<> class.. There, I changed it to Array equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use .Contains as below:

```
var path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
var ctf = Directory.GetDirectories(path).Contains(Path.Combine(path, "Test_Folder"));
```

This also avoids the need for DirectoryInfo altogether

Answer (score 1):

Check your directory status ( if it contains any sub directories as )

```
if(test.length >0) { // Do you coding here }enter code here
```